# Yii2 ajax request returning Error 404 and 400

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-404, yii2

My form element

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'batch_id')->dropDownList($BatchOptions, ['prompt'=>'Select Batch','onchange'=>'
            $.post( "'.Url::toRoute('week/getbatchdata').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                        .done(function( data ) {
              var BatchData = $.parseJSON(data);
              console.log(BatchData);
            });
        ']); ?>
```

my controller

```
public function actionGetbatchdata($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $batch = $model->getBatch();
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($batch);
}
```

I get a 404 response with no id as the complaint.
when i change the ajax .post to .get I get a 400 response

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create function like `actionGetbatchdata($id) {}` you have to add the `id` as a GET parameter (by adding it to the url). So when you use `$.post()` you're sending the `id` as a POST parameter.

I recommend making the following changes:

```
public function actionGetbatchdata($id)
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    return $model->getBatch();
}
```

By setting the response format to json to elliminate the need to json encode server side and then json decode again client side.
Js changes:

```
$.get(
    "' . Url::toRoute('week/getbatchdata') . '",
    { id: $(this).val() }
)
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Please make sure `$(this).val()` contains a value and that the code inside your action returns valid results.

Comment: Worked fine with post too. The issue was that I was trying to find a Week model that was not yet in existence so I just went ahead to use Batch::find($id)->one().

Answer (score 0):

check your controller behaviors method and make sure get-batch-data is listed there

```
    public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['get-batch-data'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['get-batch-data'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Makre sure to use camel case for controller action

```
public function actionGetBatchData()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    return $model->getBatch();
}
```

Your form element

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'batch_id')->dropDownList($BatchOptions, ['prompt'=>'Select Batch','onchange'=>'
        $.post( "'.Url::toRoute('week/getBatchData').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                    .done(function( data ) {
          var BatchData = $.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(BatchData);
        });
    ']); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! used asnswer from http://stackoverflow.com/users/829493/jagsler as I didn't have to add access controls.